# What is the difference in using "nous étudiions pendant des heures" and "nous étudiions des heures"

Tags: grammaire, expressions, verbes, imparfait

What is the difference in using *nous étudiions pendant des heures* and *nous étudiions des heures*? What is the difference in using *pendant*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sentence is at the imperfect tense (*étud**iions***) and is using *nous*, which means it is formal and literary. In spoken French, the usual equivalent is:

> *On étudiait pendant des heures.* → we used to study for hours, we were studying for hours

or perhaps:

> *On a étudié pendant des heures.* → we studied for hours, we have studied for hours

With some verbs, *pendant* might be omitted without changing the meaning but it is unlikely to happen with *étudier*.

> On a marché pendant des heures.
> On a marché des heures.

Comment: Pendant means during , So how does that sentence make meaning?

Comment: *Pendant* might translate to either "during" or "for". Here the meaning is definitely the latter.

Comment: Merci monsoir . .

Comment: You're welcome. What means "monsoir" (myevening) ?

Comment: I meant monsieur. .

Comment: I was suspecting it, sir! ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Usually you study *for* hours, so you say **nous étudions pendant des heures**. The case when some says **étudier quelqu'un (quelque chose)** is the situation where someone is studying (or doing research) on a topic for instance: nous étudions l'anatomie humaine, la musique, ..., of course one might say it in a conversation, but it is grammatically incorrect.

Comment: The OP used the imperfect *[étudiions](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/%C3%A9tudiions)*, not the present *étudions*. There was no wrong spelling in the question.